# How to split a string variable into two variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I would like to get `newdf` from `olddf` by splitting the `var` at `_` and creating a column for each. So I would like the following. Thank you in advance

```
olddf <- data.frame('Z' = c('Z1','Z2','Z3'), 
          'var' = c('A_H','A_H', 'B_J'))

newdf <- data.frame('Z' = c('Z1','Z2','Z3'), 
                    'var1' = c('A','A','B'),
                    'var2' = c('H','H','J'))
```

Comment: `newdf  <- tidyr::separate(olddf, var, c('var1', 'var2'), sep = '_')`

Comment: You can use the separate() function in tidyr package to separate 1 column into 2 columns by a separator (for example, underscore)

Answer (score 1):

**Base R:**

```
> cbind(olddf[-2], t(as.data.frame(strsplit(olddf$var, '_'), row.names=c("var1", "var2"))), row.names=NULL)
   Z var1 var2
1 Z1    A    H
2 Z2    A    H
3 Z3    B    J
>
```

With **tidyr**:

```
> tidyr::separate(olddf, var, c('var1', 'var2'), sep = '_')
   Z var1 var2
1 Z1    A    H
2 Z2    A    H
3 Z3    B    J
>
```